# Why is a div with position relative displayed on top of another with position fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-position

```css
.green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In theory the green rectangle should be on top of all others because its position is fixed, then the red and blue squares should stay behind. I don't understand what is it that the relative position of the red box does to make it sit on top of the green rectangle.

Also, when I set blue's opacity to anything that is not 1 (For instance, 0.9, which is close enough to 1 to illustrate this strange behaviour) for some reason it also sits on top of the green rectangle. Why?

This happens in Chrome and Firefox so it's probably not a bug.

Comment: all the position values (except for static) are equal. The tree order and/or z-index will define their position

Comment: Have a read about the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context)

Comment: @TemaniAfif If that's correct then in theory both the blue and the red divs should be on top of the green one. Instead, only one of them does.

Comment: blue doen't have any position set so it uses the default static position (read my comment again)

Comment: The only question that I have left is: How the heck do you find duplicate questions so quickly? It barely took a few seconds since I posted this, and I couldn't find any post in StackOverflow by myself before posting. Pete's comment with the link to the docs of the stacking context was much more useful though.

Comment: I have answered that question where I am also linking to the Spec with the full detail. As a side note, "stacking context" doesn't explain what you are want. The "painting order" does (all your elements are withing the same stacking context so it's irrelevant here)